# Memory corruption in a small ref-counted buffer class

Tags: c++

I have a simple reference counted class that holds a memory buffer. It looks like this:

```
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
struct buffer
{
    // create a buffer of length n
    buffer(unsigned n) : rc(*(new unsigned(1))), data(new T[n]) { }

    buffer(const buffer<T> & rhs) : rc(++rhs.rc), data(rhs.data) { }

    buffer<T>& operator=(buffer<T> rhs)
    {
        std::swap(rc, rhs.rc);
        std::swap(data, rhs.data);
        return *this;
    }

    ~buffer()
    {
        if (--rc == 0) {
            delete [] data;
            delete (&rc);
        }
    }

private:
    mutable unsigned & rc;
    T * data;
};


int main() {
    typedef buffer<int> numbers;
    numbers n1(10);
    numbers n2(20);
    numbers n3(30);
    n1 = n2 = n3 = n2;
}
```

I don't see anything wrong with the code. However Visual Studio and valgrind complain about memory corruption.

I've stared at this code for way too long now. Can anyone spot the error?

Comment: `mutable unsigned & rc;` ... `rc(*(new unsigned(1)))` Why are you doing this?

Comment: This is not exception-safe:  if either of the new expressions in the initializer list fails, you have no way to clean up.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis I felt like doing something different (it's toy code). Concerning exception safety you're right. However I think that a leak will only occur if the second `new` fails (of the array), and even then only the memory allocated for the `rc` variable will leak. (I'm not trying to justify my exception-unsafe code here. In the end it is still incorrect.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One problem is that when you `swap(rc, rhs.rc);` you're actually swapping the contents of the recounts, not the references.

Imagine you have this situation:

[image: Before]

When you `swap(rc, rhs.rc);`, the references to the refcounts will remain the same, and the counts themselves will swap. This is what you get after the two swaps:

[image: After]

The buffer pointers are corrrect, but the references to the refcounts still refer to the same `unsigned` objects. The value of these objects was swapped though. Notice how the buffer B has refcount 2 when seen from one of the swapped objects, and refcount 1 when seen from the one on the bottom.

You need to use pointers for the refcount, and swap the pointers, not the contents.

Comment: Wow! I would never have seen that!

Comment: I get it now. In my mind I imagine two little boxes and each one has threads attached to it. If you swap the positions of the two boxes you will drag along all the threads that are attached to it. That's the right way to do it. However, I only swapped the contents of the boxes, and left the threads as they were.

Comment: Actually I swapped the boxes and swapped one of the threads on each box. The remaining threads remain as they are.